An explicit sheaf/Cech cohomology computation
There is a sheaf cohomology computation involved in a problem I'm working on, and I'm aiming to try to solve it for the simplest non-trivial case. But I'm struggling even for that simple example.
Let $\mathcal{F_n^k}$ be the sheaf of maps such that, for any open $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$, $$ \mathcal{F_n^k}(U) = \{ s : [0,1] \times U \to GL(k, \mathbb{C}) ~~ \text{s.t.} ~~ s(0,p) = I_{k \times k} ~~ \text{for all} ~~ p \in U, s(1, \cdot) : U \to GL(k, \mathbb{C}) ~~ \text{is holomorphic}  \}. $$
I want to compute $H^1 (\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}, \mathcal{F_n^k})$ specifically for $k=2$ and $n=3$. My guess would be that $H^1 (\mathbb{C}^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}, \mathcal{F_3^2}) = 0$, which is what I'm hoping to show.
What I have worked out so far is that, given an open cover $ \underline{U} = \{ U_i \}_{i=1}^3$ of $\mathbb{C}^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ with $U_i = \{ z_i \neq 0 \}$,  $$H^1 (\mathbb{C}^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}, \mathcal{F_3^2}) \cong H^1 ( \underline{U}, \mathcal{F_3^2}) $$ by Leray's theorem on acyclic coverings. This follows from the fact that the open sets and their intersections are Stein spaces, and a special case of theorem 5.1. in section II of "Several Complex Variables IV" by Gindikin and Khenkin. (Note that for $n \geq 2$, $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is not Stein.)
This reduces the computation to that of its Cech cohomology, which, at least for these simple spaces, feels like it should not be too hard. But I can't seem to find the trick. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
